# Did Captain Power influence The Centurions?

Tags: inspiration, captain-power, the-centurions

Having read [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2504/why-do-borg-move-so-poorly-like-50s-movie-robots/2505#2505), I watched the [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-tXJpzfkscE) link to [Captain Power and the Soldiers of the Future](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Power_and_the_Soldiers_of_the_Future).

It reminded me of [The Centurions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Centurions_%28TV_series%29). So much is similar, from the power suits to the cyborg enemy and even the line up of heros (and their abilities) seems identical: see *[this YouTube clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szjcCB8m3G8)*.

Anyone know if it is more than a coincidence?

Comment: on a related note, [MANTECH robot warriors](http://rebelwookiee.blogspot.com/2008/06/retro-toybox-mantech-robot-warriors.html) are another thing that predate The Centurions and might have a influence on them.

Comment: @DavRob60 - nice, I'm glad I'm not the only one with knowledge of 80s cartoons. =:-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think so. The Centurions slightly predates Captain Power. And power suits of that type have been a staple of scifi for a while anyway. Japanese sentai and Kamen Rider come to mind.

Still, those two are among the coolest shows of my youth! ^^

Comment: good point. Perhaps it was the other way around? =:-)