# Identifying an animated TV series set in a post-apocalyptic world where robots have taken over the world

Tags: story-identification, robots, post-apocalyptic

Robots have taken over the world, and there is a small group of dedicated Fighters who are fighting them. All they have is small arms, like pistols and rifles.

Very gritty,  similar to The Terminator movie  but it all happened in the future time where the robots were hunting the last humans. Very post-apocalyptic.

If I remember correctly, the robot fortresses looked like little metal pyramids from afar.

Comment: When did you watch it? How old was it? What language was it in? What country was it made/shown in? Any detail you can remember might help someone identify it! See also [our](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) [guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9336/31394) on asking good story-ID questions.

Comment: I've never actually seen the show, but the description sounds quite like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Power_and_the_Soldiers_of_the_Future

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3432/1990s-sci-fi-series-where-humans-in-armed-suits-fight-robots

Answer (score 5):

Just like **andrewsi** (see comment below the original question), my instant reaction to the question is [***Captain Power and the Soldiers of the Future***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Power_and_the_Soldiers_of_the_Future), a partly live-action / partly CGI-animated, post-apocalyptic 1987-1988 Canadian television series that also aired in the US.

The relevant plot points are:

- Intelligent machines ("Bio-Mechs") created by Lord Dread have taken over the world in the 22nd Century and are hunting down and subjugating the remains of the human race (survivors are "digitized" and stored in a supercomputer called "OverMind")
- Captain Power and his team of soldiers lead the resistance against Lord Dread's machine empire
- They mainly carry small arms
- The show has a gritty, dystopian feel with muted, dim hues

[image]

[image]

Finally, you can see the **pyramid-like** fortress of Lord Dread at 00:30 in the show's intro sequence:

**Interesting Side Notes:** J. Michael Straczynski (of *Babylon 5* fame) was a writer for the series, and the show featured semi-interactive elements that responded to toys released in conjunction with the show.  Also, costumes from *Captain Power* were [recycled and used for the Borg on *TNG*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93558/were-the-borg-inspired-by-lord-dread?s=1%7C2.8519)....