# What was the first depiction of Robots/Androids performing faster than humans in movies?

Tags: movie, history-of, robots

In the movie *Aliens*, there is a scene where Bishop does [his "thing with the knife"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NT0epw9P7-o), showing speed and accuracy that no human would have. In *Star Trek:TNG* we often see Data entering commands/queries into the computer more quickly than humans could accomplish.

In contrast, one can recall Robot from *Lost In Space* [being fairly awkward](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USJoor2HRZo) (though [less so than the Borg](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2504/why-do-borg-move-so-poorly-like-50s-movie-robots)). As that linked question implies, many 1950s robots were fairly mechanical and slow.

When did the depiction of androids/robots as faster than humans enter into the film world?

Comment: FWIW, I'm not sure Bishop did it _that_ much faster than what humans can actually do. This is just the first example I've found, but I've seen faster in the past: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZV0qVmZ4DsU

Comment: For the Trivia Super Bowl, the knife handed to Bishop by is an [Explorer MM-IV](http://forum.alienslegacy.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15254), nearly identical to a Gerber-Mk II. Apparently [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerber_Mark_II) currently disinforms on this.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have literal hard evidence, but my best guess would be Hymie from "Get Smart" (1966).  The lovable robo-agent could simulate all human reflexes while being immensely stronger.

If Hymie doesn't fit your needs, I would say Ruk for sure, appearing a few months later on "Star Trek".  There's never any sense of "awkward" in Ruk's menacing movements.

Answer (score 3):

*Westworld*, released 1973, depicted bunches of androids that were nearly indistinguishable from human -- most notably, The Gunfighter (played by Yul Brynner) who was capable of beating most humans in a showdown.

Answer (score 3):

In Fritz Lang's groundbreaking 1927 film, *Metropolis*, Maria (Brigitte Helm) is depicted as a robot with humanoid skin, and in one scene is shown to dance seductively enough to drive men to distraction -- in fact, she was indistinguishable from human until her skin was destroyed.

Comment: Is that anything to do with being "faster"?

Comment: If "faster" is the only criterion, see my other answer, *Westworld*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much of the stories/books description made it into the film/TV adaptation, but [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Link) two stories of Adam Link, a robot created by Eando Binder (a pen name for two brothers) were combined under the title of one, "I, Robot" on *The Outer Limits* in 1964.  The same two stories were remade for the revival of the program in 1995.

In the stories (since collected into at least one book, titled *Adam Link, Robot*, likely because by the time it was collected Asimov had a much better known *I, Robot*), Adam was both stronger and faster than a human, as well as having a very well developed ethical and moral sense -- in other words, he was everything a human ought to be, and then some.

The Adam Link stories first appeared in the late 1930s, with "I, Robot" published in *Amazing Stories* in the January, 1939 issue.